# Python Pandas replace values in one column based on conditional in multiple other columns

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements, nan

Working with the dataframe df:

```
Product_ID | Category_A   | Category _B
1232             0              0 
1343             Unknown        X
2543             Nan            0 
2549             Y              Y
0349             X              X
8533             Y              X
```

I would like to create a new column Category_Final, with the following rules:

- If Category_A is 0, Unknown or Nan, Category_Final should be "Unknown"
- If Category_A is the Same as Category_B, Category_Final should be 0
- If Category_A is different than Category_B,Category_Final should be X

Expected Output:

```
Product_ID | Category_A   | Category _B | Category_Final
1232             0              0            Unknown
1343             Unknown        X            Unknown
2543             Nan            0            Unknown
2549             Y              Y            0
0349             X              X            0
8533             Y              X            X
```

I managed to get the logic for 0 and X, but I don't know how to include the Unknown Logic.

```
df['Category_Final'] = np.where(df['Category_A'] != df['Category_B'], 'X', '0')
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think in these cases that numpy select gives the most readable solution:  [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested `np.where`

```
df['Category_Final'] = np.where((df['Category_A'].isnull() | \
                                              (df['Category_A'] == 'Unknown') | (df['Category_A'] == '0')),\
                                              'Unknown', np.where(df['Category_A'] == \
                                                                  df['Category_B'], 0, 'X'))
```

Output

```
Product_ID  Category_A  Category_B  Category_Final
0   1232    0            0            Unknown
1   1343    Unknown      X            Unknown
2   2543    NaN          0            Unknown
3   2549    Y            Y              0
4   349     X            X              0
5   8533    Y            X              X
```

Comment: perfect! I knew I was close, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After your current line, try this:

```
mask = ((df.Category_A.isnull()) | 
        (df.Category_A == 'Unknown') | 
        (df.Category_A == 0))
df.loc[mask, 'Category_Final'] = 'Unknown'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Category_Final'] = (
    df.apply(lambda _: "0", axis=1)
    .where(df['Category_A'] == df['Category_B'], "X")
    .where(~df['Category_A'].isin(["0", "Unknown", np.NaN]), "Unknown")
)
```

Comment: FYI code only answers are frowned upon